# "not only.... but also..." in questions?

Tags: conjunctions, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions, grammatical-person

Here is a multiple-choice question:

> _____ not only I but also he going to Paris?
>
> A. **Am**
> B. **Is**
> C. **Are**
> D. **Be**

Which choice is correct?

Comment: B and D are obviously false. "Am" would be logical but sounds odd. "are" in in connection with "I" I have only seen in the the question tag "aren't I?" Nice problem.

Comment: @Robusto This question is more complex than that question. I wouldn't say it's a duplicate.

Comment: I think this sounds more natural: "I am going to Paris - is he also going?"

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough question indeed. There are two good choices: *am* and *are*.

The problem comes with picking the word that fits with/links to *I* and *he* **in that order**.

***Are***
This is not the correct answer but can be debated. When including yourself in a group, you put yourself last: *he and I*. Since this is first-person plural, you use *are*. However, since the sentence puts *I* first, the previous rule is broken so *are I and he* won't work.

***Am***
This is the correct answer. When referencing yourself, you say *I am*. The sentence puts *I* first instead of *he*, which allows for this rule.

The reason the *am* rule is followed and not the *are* rule is because the structure of the sentence (*but also*) splits *I* and *he* into different parts, thus breaking the *are* rule.

Answer (score 0):

Do we answer the question "who's there" with "only I" or "it is I"? It may be grammatical but it sounds absurdly artificial and must have done so for a century or more. "It's only me" in the third person is what sounds natural. The same with your problem construction. "Am not only I..." is what confounds the rest of the sentence. The idiomatic solution would be to make you and him both into third persons: "Is it not only me but also him going to Paris?"